# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_n>0$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n<1.$$ Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Initially, I tried:

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n<1 &\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\ln\left(\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n}<e^0\\ &\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)}<e^0\\ &\implies \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)<0
\end{split}$$

I got slighty desparate for an answer so I assumed that the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)$ exists.

Since the limit exists and $a_n>0$ then:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^\frac{1}{n}
$$

Combining this with the inequality results in:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(a_n)<0
$$

If anyone has any suggestions, I'll gladly listen. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n<e^{-a}<1$$
(so, $a>0$). For $n$ large enough, say $n\ge N,$
$$\log a_{n+1}-\log a_n\le-\frac an.$$
So,
$$\log a_{n+1}\le\log a_N-a\sum_{k=N}^n\frac1k.$$
Since the harmonic series diverges, we deduce
$\log a_n\to-\infty,$ i.e. $a_n\to0.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$b_n=\left ({a_{n+1}\over a_n}\right )^n$$ Then $a_{n+1}=a_1b_1b_2^{1/2}\ldots b_n^{1/n}.$ If $b_k<r<1$ for $k> n_0$ then $$a_{n+1}\le a_1b_1b_2^{1/2}\ldots b_{n_0}^{1/n_0}r^{{1\over n_0+1}+{1\over n_0+2}+ \ldots + {1\over n}}$$ The right hand side tends to $0.$ Therefore $\lim a_n=0.$